# Rxjs - Mapping from json to typescript interface

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

So, as I've been exploring this new space I needed to do a Web API call. Theres a lot of confusion out there between the versions of everything. Anyhow, I found something that works, and I know "best practice" is a bit too subjective. However, what I don't know is if there is a more *direct* way to do this.

Here is the format of the response I'm seeking:

```
export interface AuditDetail {
  updatedAt: Date;
  updatedBy: string;
}
```

Here is the server-side model:

```
[DataContract]
public class PlanHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my Angular service:

```
getAuditDetails(planId: number, fieldName: string, fieldValue: string): Observable<AuditDetail> {
    //return of({ updatedAt: new Date(), updatedBy: "Hawchorn" }); //Tooltip displays data

    interface PlanHistory    //Created because couldn't figure out how to directly map from Json to an Audit Detail. 
    {
      UpdatedAt: Date;
      UpdatedBy: string;
    }

    this.log("Retrieving Audit Details");
    return this.http
      .get<PlanHistory>(this.webApiUrl +
        "PlanHistories?planId=" +
        planId +
        "&fieldName=" +
        fieldName +
        "%20&fieldValue=" +
        fieldValue).pipe(map((response: PlanHistory) => {
          return <AuditDetail>{ updatedAt: response.UpdatedAt, updatedBy: response.UpdatedBy };
      }));
  }
```

*That* works. But I hate making that intermediate interface.

So how do I do the same thing, directly from JSON to `AuditDetail`?

Comment: You need to have the same name vars in the models, to do not use a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have the Web API return camelCasing output, so you don't have to change the casing. See [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization):

> To write JSON property names with camel casing, without changing your
>   data model, set the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` on the
>   serializer:
>
> ```
> var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
> json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
> ```

Then your code becomes:

```js
getAuditDetails(planId: number, fieldName: string, fieldValue: string): Observable<AuditDetail> {
    this.log("Retrieving Audit Details");
    return this.http
        .get<AuditDetail>(`${this.webApiUrl}PlanHistories?planId=${planId}&fieldName=${fieldName}%20&fieldValue=${fieldValue}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapping should be inferred, only difference is your casing, could you not update to make the names match?

Comment: In this case sure, but I'd like to learn how in case i really do have to map something over.

But beyond that,  *all of the UI project* casing is camel. And every property within the webservice using PascalCase.  I dont want to break convention, and i dont want to do that scope of a refactor.