# mapping interface to json data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I have an interface INavigation that have field names different from the fields in the JSON data.  How do I go about mapping the fields from the interface to the JSON data?

Here is the code:

INavigation.ts

```
export interface INavigation {
  Id: number;
  AppId: number;
  NavId: number;
  Name: string;
  ParentId: string;
  PageURL: string;
  Position: string;
  Active: string;
  Desktop: string;
  Tablet: string;
  Phone: string;
  RoleId: string;
  Target: string;
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "NavAppId": 1,
    "NavId": "1FGP",
    "NavName": "Home",
    "NavParentId": "",
    "NavPageURL": "?p=home",
    "NavPosition": "Top",
    "NavActive": "Y",
    "NavDesktop" : "Y",
    "NavTablet" : "N",
    "NavPhone": "Y",
    "NavRoleId" : "6,17,28,43,44,49,50,59,60,63,64,77,78,79,80,81",
    "NavTarget": "_parent"
}
```

Here is the method in the service that's getting the data from the JSON file:

```
   getNavigations(appId: any): Observable<Array<INavigation>> {
      return this.httpClient.get<Array<INavigation>>('../assets/navigations.json')
                  .pipe(
                    map(data => data.filter(navigation => navigation.NavAppId === appId))
                  );

   }
```

Comment: I'm working on a stackblitz for you. In the meantime, your interface defines Id twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vooy5) should give you what you want.

The mapping operation looks like this:

```
map((data: any[]) => {
  return data.map((navigation: any) => {
    return <INavigation> {
      Id: navigation.Id,
      AppId: navigation.NavAppId,
      NavId: navigation.NavId,
      Name: navigation.NavName,
      ParentId: navigation.NavParentId,
      PageURL: navigation.NavPageURL,
      Position: navigation.NavPosition,
      Active: navigation.NavActive,
      Desktop: navigation.NavDesktop,
      Tablet: navigation.NavTablet,
      Phone: navigation.NavPhone,
      RoleId: navigation.NavRoleId,
      Target: navigation.NavTarget
    }
  })
})
```

Also, you might want to use a class that implements the interface which in the constructor accepts a JSON object and do the mapping there. This would make reuse easy. You can see how to do just that in this alternative [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ine3xv)

You could, of course, skip using the interface altogether and just use the class.

Comment: using `any` feels like a lazy approach, specially considering that you do know how the objects in the json file look like

Comment: Is there a best practice of when to use a class over an interface?

Comment: An interface in most languages describes the properties a class has. A class is useful when you want to add functionality. An interface simply defines the properties.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing attributes in the INavigation interface? Use the same name as JSON data. 
following is my example (angular):
My postService code:

```
     getPosts(){
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').map(res =>res.json());
  }
```

In my component.ts file, I import the service and then:

```
pos:po[];
constructor(private postsService:PostsService) {

    // get object from url.
    this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(posts=>{
      console.log(posts);
      this.pos=posts;
    })
   }

        interface po{
      id:number;
      title:string;
      body:string;
    }
```

the JSON data I grab from the url has the same attributes as my po interface. I think that's why your code is not working.

Comment: I currently have the interface attributes as the same names as the JSON data.  But I wanted to see how to keep the attribute names different between the interface and JSON data.

Comment: I am not sure if it could be working. Have you found any example online?

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118204/rxjs-mapping-from-json-to-typescript-interface.  I'm not sure what changes I need to make to the method that I have in the service though.